# jQuery: Get return of an onclick-function from an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Is there a way to get the return-value of an onclick-function like `confirm` into a jQuery-function?

I have links which have an onclick-event for confirmation which returns true or false:

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Sure?');" class="delete" href="delete.php">Delete</a>
```

This is a given structure and I have no possibility in changing it.
But I would like to do something like this:

```
$('a.delete').click(function() {
    if (confirm_from_onclick == true) {
        //do some more before really returning true and following the link
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no way for you to change the *HTML markup*, you need to remove the complete `onclick` inline-handler from that node and to it in your unobtrusive event handler.

This could look like:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function(_, anchor) {
        var onclk = anchor.onclick;  // store the original function
        anchor.onclick = null;       // delete/overwrite the handler

        $(anchor).bind('click', function() {
            if( onclk() ) {
                // do something
            }
            return false;  // call stopPropagation() + preventDefault()
        });
    });    
});
```

Since you're dealing with an `onclick` inline-event handler, you cannot stop or prevent that from firing with an unobtrusively bound event handler. It'll always fire first, so you need to completely remove the original event.

You don't really need to store the function, you also could just set the `onclick` to `null` and rewrite the logic in your own event handler. I did it for convenience only.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/em9KP/

Comment: jAndy - This is a nice solution. Could you please just explain this one bit: $('a').each(function(_underscore_, anchor), specifically the function(_underscore_, anchor) part? I've never seen this before. (Comments don't like underscores apparently)

Comment: @JackWilson: The `.each()` method passes two things into it's callback. The *index* and the actual *element*. Since I have no application for the *index* value in this snippet, I just use an underscore. I could also just write "index" or "foobar".

Answer (score 3):

Really simple answer and might not be exactly what you're looking for, but why not remove the "onclick" event from the anchor, then handle everything inside the click function?

As in, create the confirm dialog inside the function.

```
<a class="delete" href="delete.php">Delete</a>

$('a.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Sure?')) {
        //do some more before really returning true and following the link
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: 
Sorry! Missed the part where you mentioned that it's a set structure and you have no way of changing it. Working on an alternative.